# Sending a message to turtlesim

Tags: ros, turtlesim, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone point me to an example of how to send a linear/angular message to turtlesim from a C++ program, including declaration of the publisher and message type.  Basic, I know... but it's not obvious to me how to do this from the tutorials and docs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11580/sending-a-message-to-turtlesim/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Check out the turtlesim teleop package.](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/joystick_drivers_tutorials/trunk/turtle_teleop/src/teleop_turtle_joy.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-10-18**:
Thanks David.  This was a great help.